# Python Variable scope methods

Tags: python

I have this segment of python code. I want to have a global variable called filetext. However, it does not work as intended, I want to modify the filetext variable in the first method and then use this in the second method.

```
filetext = "x"

def method1():

    filetext = "heyeeh"

def method2():
    print(filetext)
```

This yields "x". How come, and how can I overcome this?

Comment: Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement).

Comment: declare your variable as global since it is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`global`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) here, without which python will create a new copy of variable with the scope limited to that function which is `method1()` here. Hence your code should be as:

```
filetext = "x"

def method1():
    global filetext  # added global here
    filetext = "heyeeh"

def method2():
    print filetext
```

Sample run:

```
>>> method2()   # print original string
x
>>> method1()   # Updates the value of global string
>>> method2()   # print the updated value of string
heyeeh
```